# Netbeans Add a jar file to the glassfish library

Tags: netbeans, jar

Im using Netbeans 8.0.2,
For some reason the `cdi-api.jar` is missing from the glashfish libraries,
so i have to add the jar manually each time i create a new project,
i tried adding this jar to the `Java EE from GlassFish` list under Tools -> Libraries,
but it didn't show up when i create a new project.

So how can i add the jar file to that list?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
Some of the classes, that used to be before in "weld-osgi-bundle.jar" are now moved to "cdi-api.jar". And this is causing now troubles ....
As far as I understand, there is no "nice and clean" fix so far.
Just add "cdi-api.jar" as a jar to your project libraries (Right click over Libraries->Add JAR/Folder)

More info here: [Bug 247013 - cdi-api.jar is missing from glassfish 4.1 libraries](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=247013)

"So I Got That Goin' For Me, Which is Nice" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

take admin rights, go to the glassfish installed folder, put the required jar in this path:::

```
$GF_HOME/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/
```